# letters described by parametric curves

Tags: parametric, curves

so I lately was messing around with parametric curves a little bit and I was wondering whether or not it would be possible to describe whole Letters as a parametric curve. I think that it probably is possible but I was not able to find anything yet, so I'd be glad if anyone here could show me how to do that.

Greetings from Germany and have a nice day:)

Comment: You mean when the arc is drawn in the shape of English  alphabets?

Comment: Fonts typically use cubic or quadratic [Bézier curves](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiO4_up5cfTAhVT22MKHfZND2cQFgguMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FB%25C3%25A9zier_curve&usg=AFQjCNGSJKrTWoZOWZOFJgE_qtdzOlIkfQ) to represent outlines of letters.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178892/can-i-visualize-the-bezier-control-points-of-a-letter-in-tex and http://learn.scannerlicker.net/2014/04/16/bezier-curves-and-type-design-a-tutorial/

Comment: Okay, I think I can work with this. Thanks a lot :)